# IE printing value of input as well as text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

I am looking to print a form (customer request) and when I go to print in IE (IE 11) I am running into a very strange issue where it wants to print both the text and value of an input box.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="carsDumped-input">Cars Dumped</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="carsDumped-input" value="" tabindex="12">
</div>
```

And here is a screenshot of how it prints:
[Print view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2LAr.png)
I would like to hide the "value" of the input showing up as I would rather have something besides "null" show up when there hasn't been a value entered.

Anybody else have this issue or know how to fix it in CSS? This is only happening for me in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "the text of an input box"? Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue, preferably as a stacksnippet here in the question, or a jsfiddle. I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gxfqf6m/), but it doesn't behave anything like your screenshot.

Comment: the text as in .text()....what the users have input. I can work on making a fiddle - however it's hard to show exact functionality as it only happens when printing the page.

Comment: So it isn't visible in the print preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I figured out the issue. It was a mistake on my part that was actually in the JavaScript. Rather than setting the input box .val() I was setting input box .text(). This is what was causing both the value and text to show in IE. Chrome and FF were able to work around that.